# Problema al mostrar el total

Tags: java, poo

quien me puede decir porque no me muestra el total (calculado), ya he llamado al metodo setCalcular pero el total que me muestra es de 0

Clase Clientes

```
 private String nombre = "", apellido = "", placa = "";
public String clientet = "", vehiculot = "";
private double identificacion = 0, telefono = 0, total = 0;
private int horas = 0, tipovehiculo = 0, tipocliente = 0;


public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public String getPlaca() {
    return placa;
}

public void setPlaca(String placa) {
    this.placa = placa;
}

public double getIdentificacion() {
    return identificacion;
}

public void setIdentificacion(double identificacion) {
    this.identificacion = identificacion;
}

public double getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(double telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(double total) {

    this.total = total;
}

public int getHoras() {
    return horas;
}

public void setHoras(int horas) {
    this.horas = horas;
}

public int getTipovehiculo() {
    return tipovehiculo;
}

public void setTipovehiculo(int tipovehiculo) {
    this.tipovehiculo = tipovehiculo;
}

public int getTipocliente() {
    return tipocliente;
}

public void setTipocliente(int tipocliente) {
    this.tipocliente = tipocliente;
}

public void setCalcular() {

  Vehiculos vehiculos = new Vehiculos();
    switch (tipovehiculo) {
        case 1:
            vehiculos.setCarro();
            break;
        case 2:
            vehiculos.setCamioneta();
            break;
        case 3:
            vehiculos.setBus();
            break;
        case 4:
            vehiculos.setMoto();
            break;
    }
}
```

Clase Vehiculos

```
public class Vehiculos extends Clientes {

public void setCarro() {
    switch (getTipocliente()) {
        case 1:
            vehiculot="Carro";
            clientet="A";
            super.setTotal((3500 * getHoras()) + ((3500 * getHoras()) * 0.25));
            break;
        case 2:
            super.setTotal((3500 * getHoras()) + ((3500 * getHoras()) * 0.15));
            break;
        case 3:
            super.setTotal((3500 * getHoras()));
            break;
    }
}

public void setCamioneta() {
    switch (getTipocliente()) {
        case 1:
            super.setTotal((5000 * getHoras()) + ((5000 * getHoras()) * 0.25));
            break;
        case 2:
            super.setTotal((5000 * getHoras()) + ((5000 * getHoras()) * 0.15));
            break;
        case 3:
            super.setTotal((5000 * getHoras()));
            break;
    }
}

public void setBus() {
    switch (getTipocliente()) {
        case 1:
            super.setTotal((6500 * getHoras()) + ((6500 * getHoras()) * 0.25));
            break;
        case 2:
            super.setTotal((6500 * getHoras()) + ((6500 * getHoras()) * 0.15));
            break;
        case 3:
            super.setTotal((6500 * getHoras()));
            break;
    }
}

public void setMoto() {
    switch (getTipocliente()) {
        case 1:
            super.setTotal((3000 * getHoras()) + ((3000 * getHoras()) * 0.25));
            break;
        case 2:
            super.setTotal((3000 * getHoras()) + ((3000 * getHoras()) * 0.15));
            break;
        case 3:
            super.setTotal((3000 * getHoras()));
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Clase AgregarClientes

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

public class AgregarClientes {

```
public AgregarClientes() {
    Clientes clientes = new Clientes();
    clientes.setTipocliente(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el tipo de cliente")));
    clientes.setTipovehiculo(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el tipo de vehiculo")));

    clientes.setHoras(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la cantidad de horas")));
    clientes.setCalcular();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n" + clientes.getTipocliente() + "\n" + clientes.getTipovehiculo() + "\n" + clientes.getHoras() +"\n"+ clientes.getTotal());

}
```

}

Comment: 'tipovehiculo'  es un atributo de la clase Vehiculos? En ningun momento lo seteas por lo que veo.

Comment: No, es un atributo heredado de la clase Clientes, me habia faltado subir la clase AgregarClientes que es donde seteo todo, pero ya he editado el codigo de la pregunta

Comment: En la Clase Vehiculos saca la palabra 'super' que esta antes de cada invocacion del metodo setTotal, ya que Vehiculos extiende de Clientes y lo hereda.

Comment: En los metodos: setCarro(), setBus(), setMoto() - vos seteas en total al objeto Vehiculo, pero cuando queres mostrar el total, ese total se lo pedis a clientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira creo que pude lograr andar tu codigo, pero simplemente tuve que parchearlo.

Para mi desde el principio (si tomamos en cuenta el diagrama de clases) esta hecho mal.

Segun tus relaciones, tu clase principal deberia ser Vehiculo en vez de Cliente.

Tu problema principal era que en los **Switch** de clase Vehiculos, la condicion **getTipocliente()** siempre daba 0, ya que segun tu logica:

```
Vehiculos extends Clientes
```

La clase Vehiculo no tenia acceso a los valores verdaderos de los atributos Clientes.

Yo modifique las cosas solamente para el caso input: 1,1,int (o sea cliente 1, carro 1)

Clientes:

```
public class Clientes {
 private String nombre = "", apellido = "", placa = "";
 public String clientet = "", vehiculot = "";
 private double identificacion = 0, telefono = 0, total = 0;
 private int horas = 0, tipovehiculo = 0, tipocliente = 0;


 public String getNombre() {
     return nombre;
 }

 public void setNombre(String nombre) {
     this.nombre = nombre;
 }

 public String getApellido() {
     return apellido;
 }

 public void setApellido(String apellido) {
     this.apellido = apellido;
 }

 public String getPlaca() {
     return placa;
 }

 public void setPlaca(String placa) {
     this.placa = placa;
 }

 public double getIdentificacion() {
     return identificacion;
 }

 public void setIdentificacion(double identificacion) {
     this.identificacion = identificacion;
 }

 public double getTelefono() {
     return telefono;
 }

 public void setTelefono(double telefono) {
     this.telefono = telefono;
 }

 public double getTotal() {
     return total;
 }

 public void setTotal(double total) {

     this.total = total;
 }

 public int getHoras() {
     return horas;
 }

 public void setHoras(int horas) {
     this.horas = horas;
 }

 public int getTipovehiculo() {
     return tipovehiculo;
 }

 public void setTipovehiculo(int tipovehiculo) {
     this.tipovehiculo = tipovehiculo;
 }

 public int getTipocliente() {
     return tipocliente;
 }

 public void setTipocliente(int tipocliente) {
     this.tipocliente = tipocliente;
 }

 public void setCalcular() {
     Vehiculos vehiculos = new Vehiculos();
     switch (tipovehiculo) {
         case 1:
             setTotal(vehiculos.setCarro(getTipocliente(),getHoras()));
             break;
         case 2:
             vehiculos.setCamioneta();
             break;
         case 3:
             vehiculos.setBus();
             break;
         case 4:
             vehiculos.setMoto();
             break;
     }

 }
```

}

Vehiculos

```
public class Vehiculos extends Clientes {

public double setCarro(int tipoCliente, int horas) {
    double total = 0;
    switch (tipoCliente) {
    case 1:
        vehiculot = "Carro";
        clientet = "A";
        System.out.println(horas);
        total = (3500 * horas) + ((3500 * horas) * 0.25);
        break;
    case 2:
        total =(3500 * getHoras()) + ((3500 * getHoras()) * 0.15);
        break;
    case 3:
        total = (3500 * getHoras());
        break;
    }
    return total;
}

public void setCamioneta() {
    switch (getTipocliente()) {
    case 1:
        setTotal((5000 * getHoras()) + ((5000 * getHoras()) * 0.25));
        break;
    case 2:
        setTotal((5000 * getHoras()) + ((5000 * getHoras()) * 0.15));
        break;
    case 3:
        setTotal((5000 * getHoras()));
        break;
    }
}

public void setBus() {
    switch (getTipocliente()) {
    case 1:
        setTotal((6500 * getHoras()) + ((6500 * getHoras()) * 0.25));
        break;
    case 2:
        setTotal((6500 * getHoras()) + ((6500 * getHoras()) * 0.15));
        break;
    case 3:
        setTotal((6500 * getHoras()));
        break;
    }
}

public void setMoto() {
    switch (getTipocliente()) {
    case 1:
        setTotal((3000 * getHoras()) + ((3000 * getHoras()) * 0.25));
        break;
    case 2:
        setTotal((3000 * getHoras()) + ((3000 * getHoras()) * 0.15));
        break;
    case 3:
        setTotal((3000 * getHoras()));
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias, no habia caído en cuenta de ese  error

Comment: Puntua la respuesta si te sirvio, gracias